# Find a $S$ base in $\Bbb R^3$ such as $[T]_S=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let linear transform $T$,
$T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$

$(x,y,z)\to(-3x+y+4z,2x-3z,y+5z)$

find a base $S$ in $\Bbb R^3$ such as
$ [ T]_S=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-2  &2 \\ 
3 &  1&5 \\ 
2 &  1& 4
\end{pmatrix}$

my attempt:
$E=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$  which is natural base.

$[T]_E=\begin{pmatrix}
 -3&1  &4 \\ 
2 &  0&-3 \\ 
0 &  1& 5
\end{pmatrix}$

$[T]_E=M^{-1}AM$

M is the matrix that change bases $E\to S$.

hence $M[T]_E=[ T  ]_S M$ if we take $M=\begin{pmatrix}
 m_1&m_2  &m_3 \\ 
m_4 &  m_5&m_6 \\ 
m_7 &m_8  & m_9
\end{pmatrix}$

we'll have an equation which is with $9$ unknowns. Do I need to solve this?

edit :
S={$v_1,v_2,v_3$}

$[T(v_1)]_E=\begin{pmatrix}
 -3&1  &4 \\ 
2 &  0&-3 \\ 
0 &  1& 5
\end{pmatrix}.[v_1]_E=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\3 \\2
\end{pmatrix}$

$[v_1]_E= \begin{pmatrix}
 -3/11&1/11 &3/11 \\ 
10/11 & 15/11 &1/11\\ 
-2/11 &-3/11  &2/11
\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\3 \\2
\end{pmatrix}$

$v_1=${$\frac6{11},\frac{57}{11},\frac{-7}{11}$}

Comment: Do you mean the reals when you write $IR$?. If that's what you mean the correct tex code is \mathbb{R}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the basis you are looking for is $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. So you want 
$$Tv_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{bmatrix}$$ and so on...

Observe that the linear transformation given is invertible. So you can compute $T^{-1}$ and now get 
$$ v_1 = T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{bmatrix}$$......

Comment: thanks. Can you suggest me a book which includes triangulation and linear transformation matrices?

Comment: Try Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done right. or Hoffman and Kunze: Linear Algebra. The latter is a bit terse then the former.